# vertically below two object in \sup

Tags: vertical

[image: y]

This may be very simple, but I am not able to find right now, how to write the $y\ne z$ part, I have perfectly written $\sup\limits_{x,y,z \in X}$ etc ..Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss